# Rust macro to generate multiple individual tests

Tags: testing, rust, macros

Is it possible to have a macro that generates standalone tests? I have two text files, one with an *input* and another with an output. Each new line in the text file represents a new test.
Currently, this is how I run my tests:

```rust
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let input = read_file("input.txt").expect("failed to read input");
        let input = input.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

        let output = read_file("output.txt").expect("failed to read output");
        let output = output.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

        input.iter().zip(output).for_each(|(a, b)| {
            println!("a: {}, b: {}", a, b);
            assert_eq!(b, get_result(a));
        })
```

But, as you can see, if one test fail, all of them fail, since there's a loop inside a single test. And I need each iteration to be a single and isolated test, without having to repeat myself.

So I was wondering if it's possible to achieve that by using macros?

The macro ideally would output something like:

```rust
    #[test]
    fn it_works_1() {
        let input = read_file("input.txt").expect("failed to read input");
        let input = input.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

        let output = read_file("output.txt").expect("failed to read output");
        let output = output.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

        assert_eq!(output[0], get_result(input[0])); // first test
    }

    #[test]
    fn it_works_2() {
        let input = read_file("input.txt").expect("failed to read input");
        let input = input.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

        let output = read_file("output.txt").expect("failed to read output");
        let output = output.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

        assert_eq!(output[1], get_result(input[1])); // second test
    }

    // ... the N remaining tests: it_works_n()
```

Comment: Can you compare array vs. array as a test?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. The expected result is a string. The _input_ and _output_ are arrays of strings. If I compare the arrays, then I'll end up with a single test again.
But if you are asking if I can compare _vec![1, 2,3]_ with _vec![1,2,3]_, yes, thats possible.

Comment: My point is if you compare arrays you can easily see all mismatches, it won't jam at the first failure and force you to fix that before finding out about others.

Comment: @tadman I've tried that, on a few scenarios it was a bit tricky to debug which test was failing.

Comment: Maybe you could write an `assert_eq_array` function that makes the results easier to read. I've done this a lot in other testing frameworks, just haven't had occasion to do it in Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a declarative macro because a declarative macro cannot generate an identifier to name the test functions. However you can use a crate such as [`test-case`](https://crates.io/crates/test-case), which can run the same test with different inputs:

```
use test_case::test_case;

#[test_case(0)]
#[test_case(1)]
#[test_case(2)]
#[test]
fn it_works(index: usize) {
    let input = read_file("input.txt").expect("failed to read input");
    let input = input.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let output = read_file("output.txt").expect("failed to read output");
    let output = output.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

    assert_eq!(output[index], get_result(input[index])); // first test
}
```

If you have a lot of different inputs to test, you could use a declarative macro to generate the code above, which would add all of the `#[test_case]` annotations.

Comment: While this would solve one of my issues (individual tests cases), it will create another one: if I have a lot of tests, I'll need to manually add those _tests cases_

Comment: Yep, and you can write a macro for _that_.

Answer (score 1):

After Peter Hall answer, I was able to achieve what I wanted. I added the [`seq_macro`](https://docs.rs/seq-macro/0.2.1/seq_macro/) crate to generate the repeated `#[test_case]`'s. Maybe there's a way to loop through all test cases instead of manually defining the amount of tests (like I did), but this is good for now:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ( $from:expr, $to:expr ) => {
        #[cfg(test)]
        mod tests {
            use crate::{get_result, read_file};
            use seq_macro::seq;
            use test_case::test_case;

            seq!(N in $from..$to {
                #(#[test_case(N)])*
                fn it_works(index: usize) {
                    let input = read_file("input.txt").expect("failed to read input");
                    let input = input.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

                    let output = read_file("output.txt").expect("failed to read output");
                    let output = output.split("\n").collect::<Vec<_>>();

                    let res = get_result(input[index]);
                    assert_eq!(
                        output[index], res,
                        "Test '{}': Want '{}' got '{}'",
                        input[index], output[index], res
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

test!(0, 82);
```